# Why does the results of Lagrangian and substitution differ?

Tags: calculus

Problem: find maximum/minimum of $f=x^2 - y^2$ subject to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.
Lagrangian gives 4 points, while substitutions like $y^2 = 1 - x^2$ only half of them.

Could you help me understand what is going on when I make a substitution?

Answer (score 2):

For your constrained minimization problem, the Langrange multiplier method essentially looks at how $f(x, y)$ behaves when $(x, y)$ goes along constraint circle, and finds points where $f$ reaches an extremum. When using substitution, you're looking at how $f(x, y)$ behaves on the circle, when the projection of $(x, y)$ onto the $x$-axis moves along the $x$-axis. It doesn't find extrema on the boundary of the constraint domain $x \in [-1, 1]$, because the function will still grow if $x$ moves over $(1, 0)$ in positive direction along the $x$-axis.

You can still use the substitution method, but you need to check the boundaries of your constraint domain yourself ($x = -1, 1$).