# Why does a variable substitution not preserve boundary conditions?

Tags: analytic-geometry, calculus-of-variations, substitution

I am playing around with lagrange multipliers and have run into a feature I don't totally understand. I'm thinking about situations where I might just use substitution, and I've found sometimes the solution set with this method misses answers "on the boundary". My question is basically an extension of this stack [exchange post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493496/why-does-the-results-of-lagrangian-and-substitution-differ). Very simply, consider optimizing $f(x,y)$ on the unit circle, i.e.
$$
f(x,y) = -3x^2 - 10 y^2 \\
g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 -1.
$$

This problem has solutions at $(0,\pm1)$ and $(\pm1, 0)$. If I substitute $x^2 = 1-y^2$, then I get $\tilde{f}(y) = -7y^2 -3 $, which only yields the $y=0$ solutions (the other two solutions are found if substituting for $x$).

I understand after reading the post above, that the issue is $\tilde{f}$ is not constrained by $y<1$, which is of course true on the unit circle. However, I am interested in why this is the case? Doesn't the function $x^2 = 1 - y^2$ have solutions only on the unit circle (at least in $\mathbb{R}$), why does substituting this condition not preserve "all the information"?

Answer (score 3):

You should be optimizing $\tilde{f}(y)$ with the constraint $x^2 = 1-y^2$. Since $x$ does not appear in the objective function, the constraint simply implies $1-y^2 \ge 0$. So it does contain "all the information"; your mistake was discarding the constraint $x^2 = 1-y^2$ when considering the optimization of $\tilde{f}$.